# Handle `Print` button click on a webpage in `WebView`?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Web page opens fine inside my `WebView` but it doesn't respond to `print` button that is present in webpage. When I click on that `print`button from desktop browser it opens the print interface of browser where I can save the file as `PDF`. I want to do that same, I have searched a lot but could not find any information, how I can do that?

Comment: are you handling that button's click separately in the code?

Comment: This might help you: [Printing HTML Documents](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html)

Comment: I am trying to do that, but how can i recognize the `url` for that button? So I could make an `if else` statement and use [this](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html) example?

Comment: Than the problem might be with new webview's implementation. Can you check whether it is working fine with api<18 ?

Comment: @ankitaggarwal I would have to check it get back to u okay

Comment: @ankitaggarwal its same on `API 17`, How can I use that example in my `WebView`?

Comment: @halfer Did you find a solution?

Comment: @IgorBiscanin: the author of this question was Max; my avatar is above because I edited it. Max - over to you.

Comment: halfer Thanks. @Max Did you maybe find a solution?

Comment: @IgorBiscanin No luck with that one :/

Comment: @IgorBiscanin: I don't code for Android, so apologies for the simplistic question. Does your WebView connect to a website on a regular internet-based web server, or is this a self-contained thing in your app? I wonder if you can create a server-side PDF renderer, given that Android browsers won't do it for you.

Comment: @halfer My app is just a WebView wrapper of a responsive web application. Max I was able to solve the issue in mean time. I injected a javascript code in the page and handle it using interface. So I override WebViewClient and in onPageFinished injected the javascript code to handle print() function. And in a callback then call native code to show a print dialog.